# how to add custom fonts in pdf generator

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, fonts, itext

I am trying to add custom font "Ubuntu-Medium.tff" in my pdf genrator function
 i have used the following code

```
public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            try
            {
                PrintTime = DateTime.Now;
                BaseFont  bf =aseFont.CreateFont("..\\Content\\Fonts\\Ubuntu - Medium.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
               PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height);
                footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height);
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {

            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {

            }
        }
```

but when i try to run my solution it throws an error as 
"..\Content\Fonts\Ubuntu - Medium.ttf not found as file or resource."

I just want to use the Ubuntu - Medium.ttf font in my pdf. Please guide me

Comment: Try creating a `File` object using the path you passed to the `BaseFont` object. Then ask that `File` if it `exists()`. You will notice that it doesn't because your path is all wrong. What to use instead? Only you can tell, because only you know the path to `Ubuntu - Medium.ttf` (which doesn't strike me as a smart file name with those spaces around the hyphen).

Comment: Thanks for the picking the space error.I have removed the spaces now but still it doesn't work.My physical path is as follows **SolutionName -> Content->Fonts->Ubuntu-Medium.tff**

Comment: And what is the current working directory of your application?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has some age and didn't know if you had a solution yet.

Have you tried adding the file as a resource to the solution and calling the resource like the example below?

```
BaseFont bf = Properties.Resources.YourResourceName;
```

If that doesn't work, remember the file needs to exist in the output directory to work correctly, so in one of my solutions I have the file as an Embedded Resource.  If the Embedded Resource won't work for you, change the 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy if newer' or 'Copy Always'.

Comment: @Pengyy This is a legitimate answer although I'm not sure whether it is correct or not. He is not asking another questions he is implying that the OP should probably have added the file as a resource to the solution.